# LAme encoder not building

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make, lame

I am trying to implement LAME in my project to encode mp3 using this tutorial :-
http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI

When I am trying to build it :it is giving me error :
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/Users/ci5/workspace/audirecorder//jni/.
/libmp3lame/bitstream.c', needed by`C:/Users/ci5/workspace/audirecorder//obj/lo
cal/armeabi/objs/mp3lame/./libmp3lame/bitstream.o'.  Stop.

I am not able to resolve the issue.
I have made the make file just by creating a file called Android.mk.Is this wrong approach?
If yes, how do we actually make a makefile.

content of makefile as given in tutorial is :-

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := libmp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := \
./libmp3lame/encoder.c \
./libmp3lame/fft.c \
./libmp3lame/gain_analysis.c \
./libmp3lame/id3tag.c \
./libmp3lame/lame.c \
./libmp3lame/bitstream.c \
./libmp3lame/mpglib_interface.c \
./libmp3lame/newmdct.c \
./libmp3lame/presets.c \
./libmp3lame/psymodel.c \
./libmp3lame/quantize.c \
./libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c \
./libmp3lame/reservoir.c \
./libmp3lame/set_get.c \
./libmp3lame/tables.c \
./libmp3lame/takehiro.c \
./libmp3lame/util.c \
./libmp3lame/vbrquantize.c \
./libmp3lame/VbrTag.c \
./libmp3lame/version.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Does that file exist in that location? Did you copy the libmp3lame directory under the jni directory the way the directions told you to?

Comment: Yes I did as specified.

Comment: What are the contents of the `C:/Users/ci5/workspace/audirecorder/` directory? What are the contents of the `C:/Users/ci5/workspace/audirecorder/jni` directory?

Comment: jni has all the files of libmp3lame +lame.h and Android.mk ,

Comment: The .c files are in the jni directory directly? So `jni/lame.h`, etc.?

Comment: yes, they are directly in jni

Comment: That's the mistake. They shouldn't be. You should have copied the libmp3lame directory into jni. See the path the makefile is looking for the file at?

Comment: ok ,let me try this.I appreciate your help